# Google Featured Photos on mac stopped working

Tags: screensaver

I've been using Google Featured photos screensaver, and it was fine, until recently ( I guess after upgrading to High Sierra)
Right now, it comes up, it shows the photo taker's name on left down corner, but photos are all blank (just dark screen)!
Do you have any idea what's happening?

Comment: I am also a big fan of the featured photo and for several months my MacBook shows nothing but black when the screen saver working.
However, from yesterday the beautiful photos are shown again. I am happy now.

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE: Works in Mac OS Mojave!

This has been a [known issue](https://support.google.com/photos/forum/AAAAzDQC9KEttk-3w1tVq8/?hl=en) for months (since High Sierra beta came out). Hopefully the Google+ team is working on a fix, feel free to [send them feedback directly](https://davidking.xyz/google-feedback#plus) to encourage them.